# How does Matlab calculate contour lines?

Tags: algorithm, matlab, contour

What is the algorithm that Matlab uses to generate contour lines? In other words, how does it transform level data on a grid into a set of lines?

What I would like is:

- the local criterion to obtain points that lie on the contour?
- the global procedure to capture *all* contour lines?

I don't need detailed specifics about the underlying code, but the general principles would be helpful for me to interpret the output. I use `contour` (and derivatives) in my research, and want to get a sense of the numerical errors that are introduced in this step.

*It looks like a very simple question, but I couldn't find an explanation in Matlab's documentation, nor found anything on SO or elsewhere on the web. My apologies if it turns about to be easy to find after all.*

Comment: [`contourc`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/contourc.html) is the lower-level function used by `contour`, `contour3`, and `contourf`. This is a built-in so it's compiled code and not visible to the user. There isn't really any discussion of the algorithm in the inline documentation in newer versions of MATLAB. Older versions of MATLAB may have more inline details.

Comment: @excaza thanks for this comment and listing these related functions. I know about their existence, but may be helpful to others. I hadn't thought about looking for the code, but since it's compiled that wouldn't work anyway.

Comment: @tvo it was not so easy to me to find the answer ;-) Last version at http://www.mathworks.com/help/pdf_doc/matlab/graphg.pdf omits detail about the algorithm.

Comment: Thx. Great job! +1 and accept.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From [MATLAB® - Graphics - R2012a](https://web-beta.archive.org/web/20120813005801/http://www.mathworks.com:80/help/pdf_doc/matlab/graphg.pdf), from page 5-73 to page 5-76:

> **The Contouring Algorithm**
>
> The `contourc` function calculates the contour matrix for the other
>   contour functions. It is a low-level function that is not called from
>   the command line. The contouring algorithm first determines which
>   contour levels to draw. If you specified the input vector `v`, the
>   elements of `v` are the contour level values, and `length(v)`
>   determines the number of contour levels generated. If you do not
>   specify `v`, the algorithm chooses no more than 20 contour levels that
>   are divisible by 2 or 5.
>
> The height matrix `Z` has associated `X` and `Y` matrices that locate
>   each value in `Z` at the intersection of a row and a column, or these
>   matrices are inferred when they are unspecified. The row and column
>   widths can vary, but typically they are constant (i.e., `Z` is a
>   regular grid). Before calling `contourc` to interpolate contours,
>   `contourf` pads the height matrix with an extra row or column on each
>   edge. It assigns z-values to the added grid cells that are well below
>   the minimum value of the matrix. The padded values enable contours to
>   close at the matrix boundary so that they can be filled with color.
>   When `contourc` creates the contour matrix, it replaces the x,y
>   coordinates containing the low z-values with NaNs to prevent contour
>   lines that pass along matrix edges from being displayed. This is why
>   contour matrices returned by `contourf` sometimes contain NaN values.
>   Set the current level, `c`, equal to the lowest contour level to be
>   plotted within the range `[min(Z) max(Z)]`. The contouring algorithm
>   checks each edge of every square in the grid to see if `c` is between
>   the two z values for the edge points. If so, a contour at that level
>   crosses the edge, and a linear interpolation is performed:
>
> ```
> t=(c-Z0)/(Z1-Z0)
> ```
>
> `Z0` is the z value at one edge point, and `Z1` is the z value at the
>   other edge point.
>
> Start indexing a new contour line (`i=1`) for level c by interpolating
>   x and y:
>
> ```
> cx(i) = X0+t*(X1-X0)
> cy(i) = Y0+t*(Y1-Y0)
> ```
>
> Walk around the edges of the square just entered; the contour exits at
>   the next edge with z values that bracket `c`. Increment `i`, compute
>   `t` for the edge, and then compute `cx(i)` and `cy(i)`, as above. Mark
>   the square as having been visited. Keep checking the edges of each
>   square entered to determine the exit edge until the line(`cx,cy`)
>   closes on its initial point or exits the grid. If the square being
>   entered is already marked, the contour line closes there. Copy `cx`,
>   `cy`, `c`, and `i` to the contour line data structure (the matrix
>   returned by contouring functions, described shortly).
>
> Reinitialize `cx`, `cy`, and `i`. Move to an unmarked square and test
>   its edges for intersections; when you find one at level `c`, repeat
>   the preceding operations. Any number of contour lines can exist for a
>   given level. Clear all the markers, increment the contour level, and
>   repeat until `c` exceeds `max(Z)`. Extra logic is needed for squares
>   where a contour passes through all four edges (saddle points) to
>   determine which pairs of edges to connect. `contour`, `contour3`, and
>   `contourf` return a two-row matrix that specifies all the contour
>   lines:
>
> ```
> C = [ value1 xdata(1) xdata(2)...
>         numv ydata(1) ydata(2)...]
> ```
>
> The first row of the column that begins each definition of a contour
>   line contains the contour value, as specified by `v` and used by
>   `clabel`. Beneath that value is the number of (x,y) vertices in the
>   contour line. Remaining columns contain the data for the (x,y) pairs.
>   For example, the contour matrix calculated by `C = contour(peaks(3))`
>   is as follows.
>
> [image]
>
> The circled values begin each definition of a contour line.

Answer (score 4):

You can read about Marching Squares. (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Marching_squares)

Usually, linear interpolation is performed along the grid cell edges, giving contour points that you link to form polylines.

When the cells are too coarse, a preliminary interpolation, for instance bicubic, can be made to refine the mesh.

Comment: But no idea what Matlab actually uses.

Comment: +1 This is a great reference. I would have essentially used the same approach if I had to develop an algorithm. It seems likely this is what Matlab uses. I could probably verify that linear interpolation from the data to the contour line is exact (up to round-off). Well, Matlab's `linear` interpolation is actually bilinear, but this shouldn't matter along an edge. What do you think?

Comment: @tvo: about what ?

Comment: Whether that would verify that the contour is obtained from linear interpolation along edges.

Comment: @tvo: are you asking if "verify that linear interpolation from the data to the contour line is exact" would "verify that the contour is obtained from linear interpolation along edges" ??

Comment: In hindsight, I just realize that I actually have already implicitly done this verification (using the bilinear interpolation onto the contour line) in previous work.

Comment: @tvo: this doesn't make sense. There is nothing like bilinear interpolation along the mesh edges.

Comment: That was indeed the question, but if you phrase it that way, I feel like it's a silly question. ;-) Don't bother...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/122441/discussion-between-tvo-and-yves-daoust).